# Translating between properties

Tags: typescript

If I have an object, and I want to take 'rename' certain properties of that object, I might create some generic function which allows me to define types of such translation:

```js
export const fromTo = <T, U>(fromToPairs: { from: keyof T, to: keyof U }[]) =>
    (o: T): Partial<U> => fromToPairs
        .reduce(
            (p, c) => ({
                ...p,
                [c.to]: o[c.from],
            }),
            {},
        );
```

What I'd like to be able to do is find a way of defining this such that it doesn't return a `Partial<U>`, but rather just `U`, by that I mean I'd like to return a complete type. When I try this I get the following error:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'U'.
>     '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'U', but 'U' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not going to be easy without a type assertion or similar; the difficult part is that the array type `{ from: keyof T, to: keyof U }[]` doesn't specify that all the keys of U are included, but you can't guarantee a result of type U if you can't guarantee all keys are mapped to. Writing an array type that must include all properties of U is theoretically possible but not easy.

Comment: @Kaya3 Thanks - that's helpful. I'm quite open to adjusting the interface of the function such that it's easier to obtain concrete types.

Comment: Sure, I think you'd have to; it's just not easy to, unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you are looking for:

```
declare const origFromTo:
  <T, U>(fromToPairs: { from: keyof T, to: keyof U }[]) => (o: T) => U;
```

doesn't seem to really capture the intent and will probably be either incorrect or not specific enough to be useful.  For example, if you call this:

```
const hmm =
  origFromTo([{ from: "a", to: "c" }, { from: "b", to: "d" }])({ a: true, b: 123 });
// {c: any, d: any}
```

the type of `hmm` is inferred as essentially `{c: any, d: any}`, which is true enough but completely ignores the fact that `c` will be a `boolean` and `d` will be a `number`.  It's even worse if you manually specify `T` and `U` in your call:

```
interface Tea {
  a: boolean,
  b: number,
  w?: string
}
interface You {
  c: string,
  d: boolean,
  e: number
}
const hmm2 =
  origFromTo<Tea, You>([{ from: "a", to: "c" }, { from: "b", to: "d" }])({ a: true, b: 123 });
// You
```

That compiles with no error, but `hmm2` will definitely *not* be of type `You` at runtime.

So let's back up and try to describe what you're doing in the type system:

---

We're taking a source type `T`, and then copying *some* of the properties of `T` to another object with names mapped by an array of mapping objects of type `M`.  So if `T` is `{a: boolean, b: number}`, and `M` is `{from: "a", to: "c"} | {from: "b", to: "d"}`, then we want to compute `KeyMap<T, M>` as `{c: boolean, d: number}`.  Here's one way to write it:

```
type KeyMap<T, M extends { from: keyof T, to: PropertyKey }> =
  { [K in M['to']]: T[Extract<M, { from: any, to: K }>['from']] } extends infer O ?
  { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

This is complicated looking, but let's examine it.

First, ignore everything starting with the word `extends`.  That part is a trick I sometimes use to get IntelliSense to write out types like `{c: boolean, d: number}` instead of leaving them as type aliases like `KeyMap<{a: boolean, b: number}, {from: "a", to: "c"} | {from: "b", to: "d"}>`.  If you have a type `R` that is displayed as a type alias, you can usually get the compiler to expand it into properties by writing `R extends infer O ? {[P in keyof O]: O[P]} : never`.

So, the actual computation is a mapped type which iterates over `M['to']`.  Since `M` is a union of the mapping objects in your array, then `M['to']` will be the union of destination keys.  So for each key `K` in the output type, we need to find the write key in `T`.  We get that as `Extract<M, {from: any, to: K}>['from']`.  The `Extract<>` part takes the union of each mapping object and pulls out the (hopefully single) member where the `to` property is `K`.  Then we get its `'from'` property type.  That's a key of `T`, so we use it as an index to `T` to get the output type.

---

Now that we have `KeyMap`, let's write `fromTo()`:

```
const fromTo = <M extends { from: K, to: K }, K extends PropertyKey>(fromToPairs: M[]) =>
  <T extends Record<M["from"], any>>(o: T) => fromToPairs.reduce(
    (p, c) => ({ ...p, [c.to]: o[c.from] }), {} as KeyMap<T, M>);
```

This is essentially the same as your implementation, but the types are different.

The `fromToPairs` parameter is of type `M[]`, where `M` is a mapping object.  Ideally I'd just have `M` as the generic type with `M extends {from: PropertyKey, to: PropertyKey}`, but that fails to infer [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) to the `from` and `to` properties.  By introducing a `K` that extends `PropertyKey`, it [hints the compiler to infer it a literal type, see microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

This then returns another generic function, where `T` is constrained to be some type whose keys are at least those from the `from` properties of `M`.

And the return type is `KeyMap<T, M>`.  Note that I had to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to claim that `reduce()`'s accumulator was going to eventually be a `KeyMap<T, M>`.

---

So, does it work?

```
const f = fromTo([{ from: "a", to: "c" }, { from: "b", to: "d" }])
/* const f: <T extends Record<"a" | "b", any>>(o: T) => {
    c: T["a"];
    d: T["b"];
} */

const u = f({ a: true, b: 123, w: "not present" });
/* const u: {
    c: boolean;
    d: number;
} */

console.log(u); // {c: true, d: 123}
```

Yes, looks good.  The function `f()` is of the type "take any object with an `a` and `b` property and return an object whose `c` property is the same as `T["a"]`, and whose `d` property is the same as `T["b"]`.  And when we apply it to a value of type `{a: boolean, b: number, w: string}`, we get a result of type `{c: boolean, d: number}` as desired.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3kmBLA5gGIxIC2AKkgFwBQ88APOQDTwCqAfABQBmJFSAApRcMNFXgBveHzISA1iACeSHvBbwM1eIpVq28AL4BtALoBKeAF4O8LtvKWb7ANw0aydFgAWpUtbpsPCJ+Si5jaVlSCQAiKBjWLViwGKNWSP5YgCMEzW0Y4FTDCy5pKAkMGABXEFYsiQBGACYAZiNzNwB6TqkwCSgUJVZgfsHDd1wUDBAYHigwBHIQKClA8vgspCQIZZRmQPr4FCrSLJn9+gB3AH4JTDwUfHgaccnp2fmEAE0kKtX6Prwe6TfAXeAjDZbHYDMEgCTHU4zF4eVCYeC+UhNAL0HAEYhkShMZasH5VbgRGSZeBxXJJakpNJSSlyak5RL5QpGEplCrVWobRqtdpdHqk9zdCWSqXSzruDBKAAOCAA0soALJQBVMVhq+AgAAe0xQwDQTKiCmUqnU7IkghISpg8tVSiMtisgWkxmV8Em8DVxgA5FoA6ZTBJyMYAKKGmDzDAMNXpZnReADIZ5CTewwcQNREOmIx6w0gY2myY8GbwADy8GuHvgxkEPpQOktairYerjYLhng8JAADcZm4UV5k5RrIxdQajSazVTlTb4FnWN6ZyW53akA6ncpuFFKMJROI-WYnBxAkwi7PTQAlcA4YAJ4wxKIxUysNMcbgOc-joQiGIAB0cDAFUCxcIE9BcAqrBgH+pTwEByGwQ2YBAVonZIMY6FRD25jpL2UCms6GpahoaocB07ieGiahWP+4QZCyNJLjEDKGEm5qsrSHJFBYNCdAAVIgqJYDwEhXuupbwPeyAwE+NLwAAPjxn6DN+9jhn+khQYg4YvvEphuPQ9AQhGMQ5MZLzwEJsqjmifwMTwiHrJUNR1IKLSsJcsQoEgWAKnAaAlhgRTUcJoljlUEi6aZ+mQtsuwmaZEIImcMBuL2dk0aiSVARASD4FwVQdPA3S9LyHngl5vZAA)

Comment: Thank you for an interesting and thorough answer; it's great to have an answer which goes into so much detail in terms of explaining what's going on behind the scenes